# Applying a Macro with Keeping Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I want to keep my existing formula after I copy a different value to the related cell.

I am beginner of Excel VBA and there is a problem that I need to solve. I have value of previous period cumulative total at cell A1. Cell B1 is the value of this month. Lastly C1, it sums the previous period and this month and gives the cumulative total value.

So I've already written a macro for this but next month I need to copy the value at C1 and paste it to A1 so it will automatically sum a1+b1 again and write to c1. However when I apply the macro for copying the value it destroys the sum formula.

```
Sub sumfunc()
    Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
    Range("C1:C3").FillDown
End Sub

Sub copyfunc()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C3").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: If you copy that formula without absolute cell references, you end up with #REF! error because you are trying to reference a column that is left of column A. If you use absolute references then you get a circular reference because the formula contains a reference to the cell it is in. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Exactly that's what i've got. #REF! error. So basically i want it to keep summing when i copy C1 value to A1. Again and again. Next month i will be copying the previous month's value(C1) to A1 and write another value manually to B1 so that it will sum again to C1. At the end i will be applying for a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy that formula without absolute cell references, you end up with #REF! error because you are trying to reference a column that is left of column A. If you use absolute references then you get a circular reference because the formula contains a reference to the cell it is in.

You need to copy the value returned from the formula and add it to the target, not the formula itself. In this way, the value from the formula in column C will reflect a growing sum.

```
Sub sumfunc()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C3").Formula = "=A1+B1"

End Sub

Sub copyfunc()

    with Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("C1:C3").Copy
        .Range("A1").pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues, operation:=xladd
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: That's what i need. Thank you so much !